# For VR development, how do distance units in Unity3D translate to real world units?

Tags: unity-game-engine, virtual-reality, oculus, htc-vive

Other questions [like this one](http://answers.unity3d.com/questions/17670/what-does-unity-measure-distance-in.html) indicate that Unity tries to enforce a metric system, meaning that one unit should roughly equate to one meter. However, in VR specifically absolute size really does matter, because you may want things to be a certain size relative to you.

TLDR: is 1 unit in game space a meter in real space? If not, does there exist some realistic approximation?

Comment: Easy enough to test, make a 1 unit cube 1 unit away from you, does it look like a 1m box that is sitting 1m away?

Comment: @ScottChamberlain I hear you, but I think it's a useful piece of info to have floating around on the internet somewhere. I'm honestly surprised I'm the first one to ask (as far as I could tell).

Comment: Actually, I thought of a better test. Move a controller, or the headset, 1m in the real world. Then look at the inspector in Unity for your scene and see what the position value changed by. Go try the test then post the answer to your question below. I will  upvote it.

Comment: @ScottChamberlain I like your idea because it is a physically repeatable experiment with nothing subjective such as "does it seem 1 meter away." I am very interested in the result, alas i don't own a vive.

Comment: Yes, 1 unit in Unity is 1m in VR if you set everything up using Unity defaults.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I confirmed what mattnewport said in the comments: 1 distance unit in Unity is one meter.